# Good sources for formalizing pure mathematics

Tags: formal-systems

Can someone here provide a good text or lectures on formalization of pure mathematics in a symbolic language like Wolfram?

Is there a proven language (i.e. a set of symbols) that can describe or represent all ideas in pure mathematics?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're after?: https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642370113  -- I'm afraid you're probably asking the wrong forum

Comment: Version 11.3.0 includes http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html to this end. Also see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exists.html .

Comment: Pure has since the invention of informatics a new meaning compared to the mathematical knowledge of Goedel or Russell. Mathematica implements a paradigm with this look for example at [Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html). There are drawbacks like binding necessities with that. There is not only hierarchy, early or late but operator precedences that need to be ordered. Compared concepts are rules, conditions, atomics, listables and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica does not attempt to provide a complete formalization of pure mathematics. The last attempt to provide such a formalization was the *Principia Mathematica* of Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell. After three volumes the authors gave up because of mental exhaustion. Later, Kurt Goedel showed that the effort was futile and now nobody even tries to do it.